# Removing all values (strings) matching a search term from arrays located in a dictionary?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, nsdictionary, uisearchbar

Currently I'm programming an app with a tableView, similar to that one in the iPhone Contacts app.

Everything works (the sections, the bar on the right showing the titles, the cells are configured...), beside the search bar. I'm familiar how to do this (search) if the tableView's data is loaded from an array, but my situation is that its loaded from arrays located in a NSDictionary.

The dict looks like

```
Key = "A" >> Value = "array = apple, animal, alphabet, abc ..."
Key = "B" >> Value = "array = bat, ball, banana ..."
```

How can I remove all strings (from all of the dictionary's arrays) matching the search term?

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can do it like this

```
NSMutableDictionary *newItems = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (NSString *key in oldItems) {
    NSMutableArray *newArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSString *item in [oldItems objectForKey:key]) {
        if ([item rangeOfString:searchTerm].location != NSNotFound) {
            [newArray addObject:item];
        }
    }
    if ([newArray count]) {
        [newItems setObject:newArray forKey:key];
    }
}
[oldItems release];
oldItems = [newItems retain];
```

I don't know if this is the best way to do it or even if it's faster enough but let me know if this works for you.

Comment: no it doesn't :( i need it for searching a tableView. After I enter the first letter and reload the tableview, I only see strings that DO NOT contain the letter. After that the app crashes :(

Comment: Well your question says (and I quote) `How can I remove all strings (from all of the dictionary's arrays) matching the search term?` I understand that after searching your table should contain terms that **DO NOT** contain the search term... What am I missing? And can you please tell me where it crashes?

Comment: i don't know, i don't get an error log... and I'm really sorry for asking wrongly. I meant how can I only keep strings containing the search term

Comment: I've modified the answer to do what you need (that is keep the values that only contain the search term). Let me know if you still got an error.

Answer (score 1):

Did you want to update the existing Dictionary with the new Array that excludes that string?

```
NSMutableDictionary* excludedDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:existingDictionary];

for(id key in [existingDictionary allKeys])
{
   NSArray* existingArray = [existingDictionary objectForKey:key];
   NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self != %@", excludedString];
   NSArray* excludedArray = [existingArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
   [excludedDictionary setObject:excludedArray forKey:key];
}
existingDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:excludedDictionary];
```

This will replace your existing dictionary with one that doesn't have the string in it...

Answer (score 1):

From you comments, I understand that you want to filter the table contents on the basis of what the user enters in the text field. For this, you do not need to modify your dictionary at every character change. The `UISearchDisplayController` is provided for exactly this scenario. Have a look at the reference for details: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html.

HTH,

Akshay